# Limit join to one per row

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have many players, each with a numerical rating, stored in a `ratings` table that keeps track of both current and historical ratings (i.e. it has `player_id`, `rating`, and `date` columns).

How would I go about fetching the current rating of each player? As in, the rating with the most recent date.

`select * from players join ratings on ratings.player_id=players.id` would fetch every rating a player has ever had... do I need a `group by` in there? I'm struggling to see how though.

Comment: Please always include the **version** of your server! This criterion is **especially** important for MySQL which has made several important improvements recently!

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic [greatest-n-per-group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. I would urge you to look at that link (and also [here](http://artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php) - search for "Within-group quotas (Top N per group)") to learn about this important SQL functionality! That second link's entire page is a great resource for learning SQL generally - plus it's specific to MySQL!

In order to solve your particular problem (n = 1), I did the following (for versions < 8, see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=664c5753095ca6f10215a69108f58c3f) - see below for 8):

Create and populate a rating table:

```
CREATE TABLE rating
(
  rating_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  player_id INTEGER NOT NULL,  -- have FOREIGN KEY to player table!
  rating TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  rating_date DATE NOT NULL 
);
```

And populate it:

```
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, rating, rating_date)
VALUES
(1,  3, '2013-09-23'),
(1,  4, '2016-04-07'),
(1,  5, '2018-11-17'),
(2,  8, '2015-09-23'),
(2,  7, '2017-09-23'),
(2,  6, '2020-01-03'),
(3, 15, '2011-05-30'),
(3, 17, '2012-02-11'),
(3, 14, '2014-12-14');
```

### 1st query:

Get each `player_id` and the `MAX()` of their rating date, which I'm implicitly assuming is their current rating. You may want an `is_still_playing` field in the `player` table to take account of retired players - see the edit below for joining with the `player` table!

```
SELECT r.player_id, MAX(r.rating_date) AS current_rating_date
FROM rating r
GROUP BY r.player_id;
ORDER BY r.player_id; -- Always have an ORDER BY clause!
```

Result:

```
player_id   current_rating_date
        1            2018-11-17
        2            2020-01-03
        3            2014-12-14
```

Inspection shows that this is correct.

Then we `JOIN` this query (or table) back to the ratings table but this time, we include the rating:

```
SELECT r2.player_id, r2.rating, r2.rating_date
FROM rating r2
JOIN
(
  SELECT r1.player_id, MAX(r1.rating_date) AS current_rating
  FROM rating r1
  GROUP BY r1.player_id
) AS t
  ON r2.player_id = t.player_id AND
     r2.rating_date = t.current_rating
ORDER BY r2.player_id;
```

Result:

```
player_id   rating  current_rating
        1        5      2018-11-17
        2        6      2020-01-03
        3       14      2014-12-14
```

Which, again, we can see by inspection is the correct answer.

### 2nd Query:

If you are running version 8 of MySQL, it is even easier using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) [`Window function`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) (see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d734a245ed2a5f4daf79af1b268ce511) here):

First, demo of ROW_NUMBER() functionality:

```
SELECT 
  r1.player_id, r1.rating, r1.rating_date,
  ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY r1.player_id ORDER BY r1.rating_date DESC) AS rn
FROM rating r1
ORDER BY r1.player_id, r1.rating_date;
```

Result:

```
player_id   rating  rating_date rn
        1        3  2013-09-23   3
        1        4  2016-04-07   2
        1        5  2018-11-17   1 -- << want this one
        2        8  2015-09-23   3
        2        7  2017-09-23   2
        2        6  2020-01-03   1 -- << want this one
        3       15  2011-05-30   3
        3       17  2012-02-11   2
        3       14  2014-12-14   1 -- << want this one
```

So we place the results of this query in a subselect as follows:

```
SELECT t.player_id, t.rating, t.rating_date AS current_rating 
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    r1.player_id, r1.rating, r1.rating_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY r1.player_id ORDER BY r1.rating_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM rating r1
  ORDER BY r1.player_id, r1.rating_date
) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.player_id;
```

The final result of the players' ratings is the same as above for version 5.6 of MySQL.

Window functions are **very** powerful and well worth getting to know - definitely worth the upgrade! It's also the reason why it's (again) **very** important to include your version of MySQL - all the more so with this particular RDBMS since many significant new features have been added recently.

### EDIT:

I noticed that I hadn't quite answered the full question - joining to the `player` table (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ac59b53f05fff9fa81fc2796820e78f9) - works for 5.6 onwards).

```
CREATE TABLE player  -- could have many more fields (contact, height...)
(
  player_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  player_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  player_dob DATE NOT NULL,
  player_ssn VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO player (player_name, player_dob, player_ssn)
VALUES
('Joe Sixpack',  '1995-10-15', 'X123456789'), 
('Seán Citizen', '1994-02-02', 'Y987654321'),
('Bill Person',  '1997-12-20', 'Z567891234');
```

And then run this:

```
-- Joining the above result to the player's details from the `player` table

SELECT 
  p.player_id   AS p_pid,  p.player_name, p.player_dob, player_ssn,
  r_1.player_id AS r_pid,  r_1.rating, r_1.current_rating
FROM player p
JOIN
(
  SELECT r2.player_id, r2.rating, r2.rating_date AS current_rating
  FROM rating r2
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT r1.player_id, MAX(r1.rating_date) AS current_rating
    FROM rating r1
    GROUP BY r1.player_id
  ) AS t
    ON r2.player_id = t.player_id AND
       r2.rating_date = t.current_rating
  ORDER BY r2.player_id
) AS r_1
ON p.player_id = r_1.player_id
ORDER BY p.player_id; -- only 1 record per player so no point in ordering by further fields
```

Result:

```
p_pid  player_name  player_dob  player_ssn  r_pid   rating  current_rating
    1  Joe Sixpack  1995-10-15  X123456789      1        5      2018-11-17
    2 Seán Citizen  1994-02-02  Y987654321      2        6      2020-01-03
    3  Bill Person  1997-12-20  Z567891234      3       14      2014-12-14
```

Note that the player_id occurs twice in the result set above - you won't want that for the final query - I just left both in so that the `JOIN`ing logic would be very clear! Also (and this is just a matter of personal preference), note that I use singular table names - a table is a set and therefore singular. You can find many SQL coding standards on the web - pick one and stick to it - it really does help when trying to debug!

Answer (score 0):

If you want strict semantics you need to double join: Once to find the selector (i.e. the most current rating) and a second time to fetch the rating:

```
SELECT
  baseview.*.
  ratings.rating
FROM (
  SELECT
    players.*,
    MAX(`date`) AS ratingdate
  FROM
    players
    INNER JOIN ratings ON ratings.player_id=players.id
  GROUP BY players.id
) AS baseview
INNER JOIN ratings
  ON baseview.id=ratings.player_id
  AND baseview.ratingdate=ratings.date
;
```